# UICollectionView keeps crashing unless i set indexpath.items = 1

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift3

Hi I have two codes for someone reason 1 works while the other doesn't can someone please explain why? The first function works, while the second doesn't. I'm trying to generate one cell as the type PayNowCell and every cell after that as the CheckOutCell type. However, it will only allow me to put the first cell as a CheckOutCell, the second as a PayNowCell, and every following cell as a CheckOutCell. Thanks!!! Error is index is out of bounds. And it points to this line
       cell.item = checkout[indexPath.item].

Essentially i have a dynamic array checkout[] and im just trying to insert a description cell called paynow ontop of each checkoutcell while the checkout[] grows and shrinks

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 1 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paynow", for: indexPath) as! PayNowCell //init cells
    return cell
    }else{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CheckoutCell //init cells
    cell.item = checkout[indexPath.item]
    return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paynow", for: indexPath) as! PayNowCell //init cells
    return cell
    }else{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CheckoutCell //init cells
    cell.item = checkout[indexPath.item]
    return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (checkout.count + 1) //init number of cells
}
```

Comment: Please explain more and show your numberOfItem line code also here.

Comment: Added sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Try this array for manage your collection view

```
var array = [0,[]]
```

then add

```
array[1] = [your array for index 1]
```

You can add the section for manage multi-cell inside your collection view:-

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
  return (array[section] as AnyObject).count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return array[1].count
 }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paynow", for: indexPath) as! PayNowCell //init cells
    return cell
    }else{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CheckoutCell //init cells
    let checkout = array[1] // pass here array
      guard checkout.count != 0 else {
            return cell 
       }
    cell.item = checkout[indexPath.item]
    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: var array = [0,[]]
array[1] = [your array for index 1]
what are the two above arrays? i don't get where to put them and why we need array of arrays.

Comment: For section purpose here you need a main array which having count for section 0 and 1's  row count that's why i used here try this code will work.

Comment: Ok i see. It doesn't work though. And what if I don't want to use an array for index 1

Comment: well come for learn and clear your query try this link:- https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: right. that link only uses 1 cell type and dequeues it. I understand that, but i don't know why my thing is currently bugging for two types of cells

Comment: May be fatal error for your array or cell count here.